# how to insert HTML code into a table

Tags: python, mysql, html, database, insert

How can I insert a piece of HTML Code (containing " and ') into my MySQL database?

It's not that easy for me to simply escape all the " and ' with a backslash, so I'm looking for other solutions. All the solutions I have found are depended on some programming language, such as PHP, like in [this example](http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-insert-html-code-into-mysql-database-t7421.html).

The programming language I'm using is Python, but I'd prefer a general mysql solution.

The piece of code I want to insert could e.g. look like this:

```
<tr>
<td width="140"><img alt="2345234523" src="images/stories/2345234523.png" height="105" width="140" /></td>
<td width="163">"mp3's"</td>
<td width="180">"ogg's"</td>
</tr>
```

(this is just random code, not neccessarly senseful or working)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to escape the data before it is inserted into the mySQL query. The Python library that provides access to mySQL should provide an escaping function to do this, or escape the data automatically using prepared statements. Make sure you add the `python` tag if you want the method specific to the language

Comment: is there simply no other solution than escaping it?

Comment: nope, but that shouldn't be a problem - you need to escape the data anyway to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Post this as an answer, and I will accept it since I found the function for this in the Python MySQL module I'm using here: `MySQLdb.connection.escape_string()` or `MySQLdb.connection.escape()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking:

You need to escape data before it is inserted into the mySQL query. The Python library that provides access to mySQL should provide an escaping function to do this, or escape the data automatically using prepared statements.

The reason why string data needs to be escaped is that quotes (`"` or `'`) can break the SQL statement that is used to enter the data.